Can I generate custom email links for verifyEmailBeforeChange()
In a firebase web app using cloud functions I'd like to confirm an email exists before changing it. This is achieved through verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(), but I would like to use my own email to send the link. For example, generatePasswordResetLink requires the user account to be existing before sending the email, so it wouldn't work without further revisions.
